# Python 2.7 - Invalid Literal Errors

Tags: python, python-2.7

**Python Version** - 2.7.11

I am following Zed Shaw's **Learn Python the Hard Way** and am currently at [Exercise 21](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex21.html)

I am trying to modify the code so that the script prompts the user to enter the values (age, height etc) instead of hard coding them.

With everything else remaining the same, I modified this line:

```
age = add(float(raw_input('Enter 2 numbers')))
```

..and entered two numbers `(5, 1)` which resulted in the following error:-

> ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 5,2

I replaced `float(raw_input())` with `int(raw_input())` and that gave the following error

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5,1'

Could someone please advise me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are learning Python 2 instead of the modern version? BTW, LPTHW is not recommended, for various reasons. Please see [What tutorial should I read?](http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F)

Comment: @PM2Ring Agreed on second point "*its structure tends to lead people into asking premature questions*" Such as how to read two numbers from one input when the exercise implied doing one number per input :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to split your input into two numbers **before** converting these to float; use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
while True:
    ages = raw_input('Enter 2 numbers')
    try:
        age1, age2 = [float(age) for age in ages.split(',')]
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, you did not enter two numbers, try again")

add(age1, age2)
```

I've added a `while True` loop to keep asking for correct input whenever there is an error; the `ValueError` exception is raised both if `float()` fails to convert a value or if there are not enough or too many inputs given. If conversion succeeds and there are exactly two values to assign to `age1` and `age2`, no exception is raised and the `break` statement exits the endless loop. See [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) for more details on how this works.

Comment: Thanks - but when the following piece of code tries to run

`print "Age: %d, Height: %d, Weight: %d, IQ: %d" % (age, height, weight, iq)`

it throws the error

`TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str`

Comment: @pb_ng: that's not caused by the code in this answer, because the loop can't end with either `age1` or `age2` set to a string.

Comment: @pb_ng: at least *one* of the values of `age`, `height`, `weight` or `iq` is a string, not an integer or float. You'll have to fix that in your code.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might have meant to split the values?

```
nums = map(float, raw_input('Enter 2 numbers').split(','))
age = add(*nums)
```

[`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) will apply a function, in this case [`float()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float) across a collection of items, which is a list of strings as a result of [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

`*nums` is some variant of [tuple-unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-python). It takes a collection of items, and "expands" them into the arguments needed for the function.

Alternatively, this also works, but it is simply more to type.

```
age = add(nums[0], nums[1])
```

Comment: missing conversion to float/int, also there is no indication that OP's add() function accepts a list

Comment: I used the split and it resulted in the following error
`TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'`

Comment: That makes sense. My bad

Comment: Can you add an explanation as to what `map()` and `*nums` do in your answer? I know most visitors here just copy and paste, but for those few that try to *understand* what they are copying, it'd be helpful.

Comment: Exactly - I haven't yet come across the terms `map()` and `nums` so a little information about them would be very helpful.

Comment: @pb_ng `nums` == "numbers"

Comment: Using `*` in a call is not called tuple-unpacking. That's a term usually applied to *assignment* where the left-hand target is a tuple (`var1, var2, var3 = iterable_object_with_three_values`). There is no good name for the call syntax yet. "Variable arguments", "positional argument expansion", etc. have all been applied here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters From my understanding, it does unpack the collection, so that's what I'm going to call it :)

Comment: That's your prerogative, but take into account that when you talk to other experienced Python developers, that they'll assume you are talking about  assignment instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
age1,age2=(float(x) for x in raw_input('Age_1, Age_2: ').split(','))
print add(age1,age2)
```

`.split(n)` will create a list from a string by splitting the string at each index of n. Code is the same as:

```
n = raw_input('Age_1, Age_2')
n = n.split(',')
age1 = float(n[0])
age2 = float(n[1])
print add(age1, age2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the user to input multiple values you will need to change your code up. As raw_input() can only unpack one value.

for example, you cannot input a tuple and have raw_input() unpack it

```
>>> a, b = raw_input('enter two numbers: ')
>>> enter two numbers: 69, 420
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

instead maybe try this:

```
>>>variables = []
>>>for i in range(len(<How many inputs does your function need>)):
>>>   variables.append(float('enter variable{}:'.format(i)))
>>>
>>>age = add(variable[0], variable[1]... variable[n])
```

or as others have noted try to parse your input with string manipulation:

```
'string'.split()
```

.split method is very handy. check out the python wikibooks for an overview and examples of string methods

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Strings

Comment: `a, b = raw_input('enter two numbers')` followed by entering `ab` would work, because you *can* unpack a string with two characters in them. Iterable assignment works with any iterable, and a string is an iterable.